# Perform a VBA Function on a column with an unknown number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function that various users can perform the function below on a column that will have a different number of rows for each user, but I can't figure out how to allow for the variability in the number of rows.

```
Function MKT(ByVal Temperatures As Variant) As Double
Dim Sum As Double
Dim TemperatureCount As Long
Dim GasConst As Double
Dim DeltaH As Double
Dim Conv As Double
Conv = 273.15
GasConst = 8.314472
DeltaH = 10 * GasConst
Sum = 0
For TemperatureCount = Temperatures.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Sum = Sum + Exp(-DeltaH / (GasConst * (Temperatures(TemperatureCount) + Conv)))
        Next TemperatureCount
        MKT = (DeltaH / GasConst) / (-Log(Sum / Temperatures.Cells.Count)) - Conv
End Function
```

The function works if I set the cell value to =MKT(A1:A32557), but not if I do =MKT(A:A).

I think this could help, but I'm not sure how to implement it:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

Also, is it possible to offset the values by 1 row to account for a header?

Comment: UsedRange is not always up-to-date; it is safer to rely on cell values. Ideally you would have a column that will contain a value for every row on which the function should work, and only contain values for those rows; if not, some variation on End(xlUp) should work as long as you don't also have populated cells below that table.

Answer (score 3):

or to avoid hard-coding the row limit use

```
with sheet1
  lastRowColA = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  Set rng = .range("A2:A" & lastRowColA)
end with
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lastRowColA = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("a2:a" & lastRowColA)
'MsgBox cell
Next cell
```

Comment: stupid question, but where do I put that or how do I integrate that into my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subset of Temperatures by intersecting with the Used Range

```
Dim SubRange as Range
Set SubRange=Intersect(Temperatures,Temperatures.Parent.UsedRange)
```

or as nick and osknows have posted you can use .End(xlUp), but note that this ignores hidden cells

```
Function SubRange(theRange As Range) As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = theRange.Parent.Cells(theRange.Parent.Rows.Count, theRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
Set SubRange = theRange.Resize(LastRow - theRange.Row + 1)
End Function
```